# Rendering text boxes using map function for each object in this.state array. how can i handle text in the text area

Tags: reactjs

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have a messages component in my React app. I am querying my db to get messages  and populating them in state of my component.

while rendering messages in my component, I am using map function. In addition to rendering the messages, i am adding a reply text area for each message. I am trying to capture the response message using handleInputChange and setting state. However, all the text areas in my app are displayed with this message.

```js
class Messages extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.loadMessages = this.loadMessages.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
            responseMessage: "",
            displayReplyBox: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Props from component mount", this.props);
        this.loadMessages();
    }

    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value, } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    loadMessages = () => {
        console.log("UserID IS", this.props.userId);
        API.getMessages(this.props.userId)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ messages: res.data });
                console.log(this.state.messages)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
 
 render() {
        const { isLoggedIn, userId, email, zipCode } = this.props;
        console.log("props in user dashboard", this.props);
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            return <Redirect to="./Login" />
        }
        return (
            <GFGContainer>

                <Header textAlign="center" color="teal" size='huge'>My Messages</Header>


                {this.state.messages.map(message =>
                    <Comment.Group key={message._id}>
                        <Comment fluid >
                            <Comment.Content>
                                <Comment.Author as='a'>{message.senderName} : </Comment.Author>
                                <Comment.Metadata>
                                </Comment.Metadata>
                                <Comment.Text>{message.message}</Comment.Text>
                            </Comment.Content>
                        </Comment>
                        <Form reply>
                            <Form.Input value={this.state.responseMessage} onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                name="responseMessage"
                                placeholder="Enter your response" />
                            <Button content='Send Message' labelPosition='left' icon='edit' color="teal" onClick={() => this.sendResponse(message._id, userId, message.sender)} />
                        </Form>
                        <Divider horizontal><Icon name="comments"></Icon></Divider>
                    </Comment.Group>

                )}


            </GFGContainer>

        );
    }
}

export default Messages;
```

Comment: You need to show some code for people to understand your issue.

Comment: Does Comment.Group have state? If so, are you setting the reply message to state on _that_ level? ultimately you need to give each group it's own independent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <Form.Input 
value={this.state.responseMessage} 
onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
name="responseMessage" />
```

this issue is here, all of your `Form.Input` inside of your map have the same `name` and the same property from the state as `value`

you need the name to be dynamic for example:

```
name={message._id}
```

your state should look like this:

```
  this.state = {
        messages: [],
        responseMessage: {},
        displayReplyBox: false
    }
```

then inside `handleInputChange`, you could change this part:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  responseMessage: {
    ...prevState.responseMessage,
    [name]: value,
  },
}));
```

will generate dynamically properties of `responseMessage`

then finally change the `value` to

```
value={this.state.responseMessage[message._id] || ""}
```

I think this should work

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to solve it on the same component level, then you would have to add an array of inputs of the same length as the messages (or longer if you have nested fields).

The easier alternative is to break the reply into a different component:

```
class Reply extends Component {
  state = {
    responseMessage: "",
  };
  handleInputChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      responseMessage: value,
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { onSend } = this.props;
    <Form reply>
      <Form.Input
        value={this.state.responseMessage}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        name="responseMessage"
        placeholder="Enter your response"
      />
      <Button
        content="Send Message"
        labelPosition="left"
        icon="edit"
        color="teal"
        onClick={() => onSend(this.state.responseMessage)}
      />
    </Form>;
  }
}

class Messages extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loadMessages = this.loadMessages.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      responseMessage: "",
      displayReplyBox: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Props from component mount", this.props);
    this.loadMessages();
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  loadMessages = () => {
    console.log("UserID IS", this.props.userId);
    API.getMessages(this.props.userId)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ messages: res.data });
        console.log(this.state.messages);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn, userId, email, zipCode } = this.props;
    console.log("props in user dashboard", this.props);
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return <Redirect to="./Login" />;
    }
    return (
      <GFGContainer>
        <Header textAlign="center" color="teal" size="huge">
          My Messages
        </Header>

        {this.state.messages.map((message) => (
          <Comment.Group key={message._id}>
            <Comment fluid>
              <Comment.Content>
                <Comment.Author as="a">{message.senderName} : </Comment.Author>
                <Comment.Metadata></Comment.Metadata>
                <Comment.Text>{message.message}</Comment.Text>
              </Comment.Content>
            </Comment>
            <Reply onSend={(newMessage) => this.sendResponse(message._id, userId, message.sender, newMessage)} />
            <Divider horizontal>
              <Icon name="comments"></Icon>
            </Divider>
          </Comment.Group>
        ))}
      </GFGContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

Now, each of your Reply components have indepdent state which gets updated on it's own

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to set the name of `<Form.Input>` dynamically.

Set name to `message._id` and read the input value from `this.state[message._id]`

```jsx
<Form.Input 
  name={message._id} 
  value={this.state[message._id] || ""} 
  onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
  placeholder="Enter your response" 
/>
```